# How do I enable TLS 1.3 in iOS and MacOS?

Tags: macos, iphone, tls

It's reported that TLS 1.3 (currently in draft status) can reduce connection setup delays by 30% or approximately 30ms.

How can I configure this on MacOS or iOS?

Answer (score 4):

According to WWDC2017:

1. TLS 1.3 is not enabled by default
2. You can enable this on iOS with [this provisioning profile](https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=tls13-mobile-profile)
3. You can enable this on MacOS with this command in Terminal

   `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkd tcp_connect_enable_tls13 1`

Comment: can you please share the wwdc link for this?

Comment: It's in session 709 (Advances in Networking, Part 2) around minute 37:29 in the session: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/701/?time=2249